# Not able to access shared folder from aws lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, smb

I am trying to access shared folder from aws lambda lambda is throwing below error. I am using smb.SMBConnection python library.

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

user = 'user_id'
pwd = 'password'
machine_name = 'testmachine123.mydomain'
shared_folder_name = 'my_folder'
file_name = 'test.csv'
domain = 'mydomain'
conn = SMBConnection(user, pwd, machine_name, '.', domain=domain, use_ntlm_v2=True,
                     is_direct_tcp=True)

conected = conn.connect(machine_name, 445)
if conected:
    print('connected to the server')
else:
    print('Failed to connect to server.')
    raise Exception('Failed to connect to server.')

with open(file_name, 'wb') as file_obj:
    conn.retrieveFile(service_name=shared_folder_name,
                      path=file_name, file_obj=file_obj)

row = open(file_name, 'r')
for line in row:
    print(line)
```

error message -

```
"errorMessage": "timed out",
"errorType": "timeout",
"stackTrace": [
[
  "/var/task/smb/SMBConnection.py",
  113,
  "connect",
  "self.sock.connect(( ip, port ))"
]
]
}
```

I tried to use ip address of the server too but no luck. can anyone help?
I have also added ip address in security group.

Comment: are you sure that your internet connection works good, time out error occures when you are not able to make the connection in time or connection to the server was unsuccesful

Comment: Thanks for reply. yeah, I am sure about that. also i have added the server ip address in security group too.

Comment: as per the traceback. the connection could not establish to the server and due to the timeout set on socket, the error was raised due to inablility to connect to server in time

Comment: It is working from my local machine and able to download the file. is there any way i can get same functionality from lambda?

Comment: your aws-machine does not seem to have permission for initiating a connection out of it, basically you can upload files to it, but when the aws-lambda runs it, it can not perform any connections due to no permission for internet.

Comment: I understand your point but there are 10 other lambda which are working fine. though their job is different. they are able to make API request and get the response. so i am pretty much sure that this should not be internet issue. yeah permission issue i can think of but what kind of permission? I already provided all the permission to IAM role and added IP in security group.

Comment: then i have zero expereince with aws-lambda